# Mac node serial-port not detecting connected USB device

Tags: node.js, macos, node-serialport

I am using node serialport library in my Simple node console application.
I Installed the required driver for the USB Dongle and  seems like its not getting detected.
But when i checked the mac i can see the device listed

All i can see is 
path: '/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port'
I am expecting to see the CEL EM3588 Zigbee USB stick in the list.
Am I missing something?

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
SerialPort.list().then(o=>{console.log(o)});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured the solution.
Actually even after installing the Driver for the particular dongle, Security in my Mack Was not allowing it to load.
I manually had to allow the driver to run from the Apple-->Security &Privacy -->General Tab.
Image Attached,

[image: Security and Privacy]

Once I clicked the allow button after installing the driver it started showing-up.

I ran the command

```
`npx @serialport/list`
```

and I started seeing my connected dongle